# ArrayAdapter and ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have this code which has to get a listview and populate it with an array adapter:

```
public class news extends ListActivity {
public String[] titoli = new String[99];
public String[] descrizioni = new String[99];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new connection().execute();
    System.out.println("prova1");
}

public class connection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        System.out.println("prova2");
        // All static variables
        final String URL = "http://www.messedaglia.it/index.php/archivio-news?format=feed&type=rss";
        // XML node keys
        final String ITEM = "item"; // parent node
        final String TITLE = "title";
        final String DESC = "description";
        Element e = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(ITEM);

        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TITLE, parser.getValue(e, TITLE));
            map.put(DESC, parser.getValue(e, DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
        System.out.println("prova3");
        for (int c = 0; c < nl.getLength(); c++) {
            e = (Element) nl.item(c);
            titoli[c] = parser.getValue(e, TITLE); // name child value
            descrizioni[c] = parser.getValue(e, DESC);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void onPostExecute() {
        System.out.println("prova4");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(news.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titoli);
        System.out.println("prova5");
        ListView listView = (ListView) news.this
                .findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
     }
 }
```

the log show a **Null Pointer Exception** here(line 33 of my code):

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

LOG:

```
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.messedagliavr.messeapp/com.messedagliavr.messeapp.news}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at com.messedagliavr.messeapp.news.onCreate(news.java:33)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):    ... 11 more
```

Most of you say to add setContentView(). I removed it because adding it I get this error:

> error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: is line with findViewById working? It seems that listView variable is null.

Comment: Where is you setContentView() function? You are trying to find the view before setContentView() method call.

Comment: @Francesco Ambrosini Simple Example with `ListView` - `ArrayAdapter`. Just try to follow that. Here is the [link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1516).

Comment: Add "setContentView" right after the call to "super.onCreate"

Comment: i moved the setCOntentView() before the calling of the class news. I do that because if i don't i get this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as in log :

> NullPointerException 02-07 13:38:36.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13803):
>   at com.messedagliavr.messeapp.news.onCreate(news.java:33)

because `titoli` array is empty. you are using AsyncTask for getting elements in `titoli` array then just move your adapter code `onPostExecute` method

and use

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

instead of

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to get `ListView` reference and must declare ListView id as `android:id="@android:id/list"`  in xml layout if you are using

Comment: How the titioli variable can be null if it is initialized to new String[99] before even the constructor runs?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas in case when u are extending ListActivity then it's not necessay u have layout for ListActivity and no need to use setContentView(R.layout.main);  if you are not adding your on layout

Comment: something like this?:
public void onPostExecute() {
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titoli);
     ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);}

Comment: @FrancescoAmbrosini : like this : `public void onPostExecute() { 

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(news.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titoli); 

ListView listView = (ListView)news.this.findViewById(android.R.id.list); 

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}`

Comment: But the stack trace seems starting at the line 33 in the code above. The only way how NPE could be thrown from exactly this line is that listView is null. However with an array of nulls as data for the list, the execution would probably not run much further anyway.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas : can u tell me *1.* if OP is adding elements in titoli array inside AsyncTask then ?, *2.* when u are extending ListActivity it's necessary to have layout for Activity? *3.* can OP get reference to ListView using findViewById(R.id.list) if class extending ListActivity

Comment: thank's the app don't crash anymore but it still don't work fine: it show only a white screen..

Comment: @FrancescoAmbrosini : just check Array is not empty and best way is use ArrayList instead of Array and return it from doInBackground method then use it inside onPostExecute method

Comment: @FrancescoAmbrosini : and best way is just post your AsyncTask code with question

Comment: i post the asynctasck. Can you show me how to use ArrayList instead of Array? i can't manage to do that..

Comment: @FrancescoAmbrosini : use [this](http://pastebin.com/qWteGgK3) code for adding items using ArrayList in Listview

Comment: it worked but i had to add the layout before the declaration of the ListView. I love this community. Thank's you and thank's everybody

Answer (score 2):

You are missing to set main layout

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);    <----------------here
     new connection().execute();
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titoli);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: i moved the setCOntentView() before the calling of the class news. I do that because if i don't i get this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Answer (score 1):

This is because the layout is not set on your component. First you need to call `setContentView(R.layout.my_great_layout)`, only then it makes sense to call `findViewById`.

Be sure you have a `ListView` with `android.R.id.list` id in your layout:

```
  <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
  .....
```

Comment: i moved the setCOntentView() before the calling of the class news. I do that because if i don't i get this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: This has been a bad idea. You just must have the ListView component with this id in your XML, see the edited answer above.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas : im still not clear why `setContentView` is necessary if OP is not using custom layout for Activity when extending `ListActivity`

Comment: Not only is using the custom layout but also seems complaining I would say very obviously something is missing in that layout.